# Show that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^p}$ is absolutely convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $\sum a_n^2$ be convergent and $p > 1/2$. Show that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^p}$ is absolutely convergent.

So, we have to show that $\sum \sqrt{\frac{a_n^2}{n^{2p}}}$ is convergent. Clearly $|\frac{a_n^2}{n^{2p}}| < a_{n}^2$, so this series converges by the comparison test, but I'm not sure how to get the square root.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does Cauchy-Schwarz hold for infinite sums?

Comment: Yes it does. But you can also apply it to the finite sums and then take the limit if you're more comfortable with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we know that
$$(\sum {a_nb_n})^2 \leq \sum a_n^2 \sum b_n^2.$$
Letting $a_nb_n = |\frac{a_n}{n^p}|$,
we get that 
$$(\sum {|\frac{a_n}{n^p}|})^2 \leq \sum a_n^2 \sum \frac{1}{n^{2p}} = L.$$
Thus $(\sum {|\frac{a_n}{n^p}|}) \leq \sqrt{L}$, so we have absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a self-contained, elementary proof of a relevant generalization, suppose $a_n,b_n\ge0$ for all $n$ and $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum b_n^2$ are both convergent.  Then

$$a_n,b_n\ge0\implies -b_n\le a_n-b_n\le a_n\implies0\le(a_n-b_n)^2\le\max\{a_n^2,b_n^2\}\le a_n^2+b_n^2$$

which implies $\sum(a_n-b_n)^2$ is convergent.  But $(a_n-b_n)^2=a_n^2-2a_nb_n+b_n^2$, hence

$$2\sum|a_nb_n|=\sum\left|(a_n-b_n)^2-a_n^2-b_n^2\right|\le\sum(a_n-b_n)^2+\sum a_n^2+\sum b_n^2$$

so $\sum a_nb_n$ is absolutely convergent.

In the OP's problem $b_n=1/n^p$ with $p\gt1/2$, which implies $\sum b_n^2=\sum{1\over n^{2p}}$ converges, since $2p\gt1$.